# Why do several Marvel films have this at the end?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

I've noticed that at the end of several MCU films, there'll be a message that speaks directly to the audience. So far I've seen stuff like:

- *"Thor will return in The Avengers"*
- *"Captain America will return in The Avengers"*
- *"The Guardians of the Galaxy Will Return"*
- *"Tony Stark will return"*

#### Why does Marvel do this?

I understand that it reassures fans that certain [potentially favorite] characters will be seen again, but is there anything beyond this?

What strikes me odd the most is that the messages are about major characters that are still clearly alive, and who have no reason *not* to be shown again in a future film, so, what's the need for this?

Also, Marvel doesn't do this for every film, so, what makes these different from the rest?

Comment: I think it is to grab the attention of casual viewers. It is highly likely that many hardcore fans go with their friends, who may not be that interested. If that friend likes the movie, example Thor: Ragnarok, he would see where the hero makes their next appearance.Thus, Marvel gets a guaranteed ticket sale, as well as a fan of their movies.

Comment: [TV Tropes: And the Adventure Continues](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AndTheAdventureContinues)

Comment: ^ I was going to say, I'm pretty sure this is some kind of adventure trope!

Comment: I always believed it was some reference to comics: since they are an endless series of adventures, I thought they might end by "The dynamic duo will return next month in Detective Comics" or "Is it the end of adventures from Steve and Bucky? No! The bromance will continue in...". Of course, this fits with @AbhishekMishra's answer

Comment: @Taladris completely agree with your point.

Comment: @Taladris I suggest making your comment an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most situations you're correct in the fact that it is a pointless thing to do.

For example, seeing *Thor will return* at the end of Thor: Ragnarok may seem pointless because we fans already know he's in Infinity War. However, to some casual fans who enjoyed the character/movie, it is an assurance that there will be another chance to see them again.

Another reason is also that some marvel movies may have seemed like one and done with certain characters. When Ant-Man released there was no announcement of a sequel so people were genuinely unsure if he would return.

Answer (score -3):

Because they like 80's. They really, really, really, really, like the 80's.

And you know what was in the eighties? Bond movies that have this disclaimer

James Bond will return in Pussy Gallore. I mean, he will return in Her Majesty Service.

And it show to audience that there will be more movies with their favourite character. This what distinguish Marvel from DC. Marvel is like: "We will make more movies that are fun" and DC is "meh, Snyder".

Comment: That’s not from the eighties. It was well before that.

Comment: Until the Moonraker in 1979 they told in what movie Bond will return. After that it was just "James bond will return..."